# How to add vertical space between two lines of tables

Tags: tables, line-spacing, enumitem, inline

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{abc}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate*}
      \item
        \begin{tabu}[t]{c|c}
          \firsthline
          $p$ & $p \to \neg p$ \\
          \hline
          T & F \\
          F & T \\
          \hline
        \end{tabu} \\
      \item
        \begin{tabu}[t]{c|c}
          \firsthline
          $p$ & $p \leftrightarrow \neg p$ \\
          \hline
          T & F \\
          F & F \\
          \hline
        \end{tabu}
    \end{enumerate*}
  \item
    This is the second item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I use inline enumerate to put multiple tables in a line and use forced linebreak when needed.  The vertical space between two lines of tables are too small.  How to make it bigger?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the optional argument for `\\` to add some vertical space (in the example below I used `\\[2ex]` but, of course, instead of `1ex` you can use the length that best suits your needs):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{abc}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate*}
      \item
        \begin{tabu}[t]{c|c}
          \firsthline
          $p$ & $p \to \neg p$ \\
          \hline
          T & F \\
          F & T \\
          \hline
        \end{tabu} \\[2ex]
      \item
        \begin{tabu}[t]{c|c}
          \firsthline
          $p$ & $p \leftrightarrow \neg p$ \\
          \hline
          T & F \\
          F & F \\
          \hline
        \end{tabu}
    \end{enumerate*}
  \item
    This is the second item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And even [-4pt] if you want to shorten the vertical space, it works also.